# Hasura Cannot GET /api/rest/*

Tags: nestjs, aws-fargate, hasura, aws-api-gateway

[image: Routes Image]

```
{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "Cannot GET /api/rest/get-profile-photo"
}
```

Hi guys, I'm using Hasura rest APIs and Hasura is hosted on AWS. I'm using AWS API gateway, Nestjs, and AWS Fargate. All Hasura rest endpoints are working fine on my local but I'm having this problem on the live endpoint of AWS. I'm attaching here the image of the defined route also. Please help.

Comment: Does it work locally when you start NestJs?

Comment: Yes, it works locally @omidh.

Comment: Does it work if you call the AWS API endpoint manually through CURL, Insomnia, Postman etc?